# docker fails to access a gunicorn served resource in the host

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn, simplehttpserver

I load a simple docker ubuntu image. Start up the container. Install curl in that container.

Over at the docker host. I write two python based web servers. One based of SimpleHTTPServer (hosted on port 4000) and a falcon based (hosted on 5000 with gunicorn).

The python based web server is accessible from the container shell:

```
root@430a51680859:/# curl http://172.17.0.1:4000
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the gunicorn one simply fails:

```
root@430a51680859:/# curl http://172.17.0.1:5000/quote
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused
```

Comment: The gunicorn one is probably listening on localhost only. You need to make it listening on either all interfaces or the `docker0` interface

Comment: @warmoverflow you are right...gunicorn can bind to multiple endpoints. How to make it listen to all interfaces, I don't know...

Comment: Run gunicorn with -b 0.0.0.0:5000

Comment: @warmoverflow that worked...you probably want to convert this to an answer now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gunicorn listens on localhost (127.0.0.1) only by default, while SimpleHTTPServer listens on all interfaces by default. To be able to access the Gunicorn served pages, run Gunicorn with either `-b 0.0.0.0:5000` (listening on all interfaces) or `-b 172.17.0.1:5000` (listening on `docker0` only, accessible from Docker containers).